# Usar dos variables en la salida de un script de bash

Tags: bash

Estoy haciendo un `script` sencillo para poder hacer respaldos de directorios, pero quiero que el nombre del archivo resultante sea `directorio_aaaa-mm-dd`.

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
ls -d */
echo "Elige el directorio del cual hacer el backup (sin incluir el /)"
read directorio
echo "Realizando el backup de $directorio..."
tar -zcvf $(directorio)_$(date +%F).tar.gz $directorio
```

Pero esto genera el archivo `_aaaa-mm-dd.tar.gz`

Answer (score 6):

Podrías intentar algo como esto:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

ls -d */

echo "Elige el directorio del cual hacer el backup (sin incluir el /)"
read directorio

echo "Realizando el backup de $directorio..."
tar -zcvf $directorio"_"$(date +%F).tar.gz $directorio
```

El error que tienes en el programa se encuentra en la ultima línea.

Cuando haces esto:

```
$(directorio)_$(date +%F).tar.gz
```

Al usar el operador `$()`, estás indicando que lo que se encuentra dentro del paréntesis es un **comando**, por lo tanto el ignora esto y lo omite, lo que da lugar a que quede ***_aaaa-mm-dd***.

**Por lo tanto.**

La **solución** consiste en dos pasos:

- Llamar a la variable de la manera adecuada
- Concatenar al nombre del directorio el carácter _

**¿Cómo lo hacemos?**

De esta manera:

```
$directorio"_"$(date +%F).tar.gz
```

Lo que le indicamos al intérprete es que al nombre del directorio le concatene el caracter `_`, se debe concatenar ya que si se agregase sin las comillas, así:

```
$directorio_$(date +%F).tar.gz
```

El intérprete buscaría la variable `$directorio_`,lo que dejaría el archivo con el nombre ***aaaa-mm-dd.tar.gz***.

Comment: También puedes usar `${directorio}_$(date)...`.

Answer (score 2):

Sólo comentar que deberías usar las comillas para evitar sorpresas cuando se expanda la variable y tengas un nombre de directorio con espacios:

```
"${directorio}_$(date +%F).tar.gz"
```

Quería dejar esto como un comentario pero mi puntaje no me alcanza para dejar comentarios, sólo respuestas.

Y como sólo puedo dejar una respuesta, hago un aporte más que no responde la pregunta pero es que al ver lo que quieres hacer no pude evitar pensar en usar un `select`, así te evitas que alguien ingrese mal el nombre del directorio:

```
PS3="Elige el número del directorio del cual deseas hacer el backup: "
select dir in */; do
    if [[ -d "$dir" ]];then
        tar -zcvf "${dir%/}_$(date +%F).tar.gz" "$dir"
        break
    fi
    echo "Selección inválida"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
export FECHA=($(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S") )
export NAME=Directorio_${FECHA}.backup
tar -zcvf $(NAME).tar.gz $directorio
```

Comment: sería bueno que explicaras un poco la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

La solución fue bastante simple. Sólo reemplacé  **$(directorio)** por **${directorio}**.

Comment: Fíjate que la respuesta de Ivan Botero te indicó cuál era el error y te dio una alternativa. Tú ofreces otra, también válida, pero no estaría de más aceptar su respuesta comentándolo cómo lo solucionaste. Al fin y al cabo, parece que él te ayudó a llegar al problema.